# How to calculate the first order correction to the asymptotic solution to a second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, asymptotics, substitution, implicit-function

Consider the following differential equation:
$$
\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{cases}
1-e^{-\frac{y}{\epsilon}},\space\space\space x<0\\
e^{-\frac{1-y}{\epsilon}}-1,\space\space\space x>0
\end{cases}
$$
subject to $\frac{dy}{dx}\to0$ as $y\to0,1$. I am interested in the behaviour of the solution in the limit $\epsilon\to0$.
Solving this exactly leads to the implicit solution:
$$
-\frac{x}{\epsilon}=\begin{cases}
f\left(\frac{1}{2\epsilon},\frac{y}{\epsilon}\right),   x<0\\
f\left(\frac{1-y}{\epsilon},\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\right),   x>0
\end{cases}
$$
where
$$
f(y_{1},y_{0})=\int_{y_{0}}^{y_{1}}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y+e^{-y}-1}}
$$
I have been able to expand the solution to get
$$
y\sim\begin{cases}
A\epsilon e^{\frac{x+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2\epsilon}}},   x<-\sqrt{2}\\
\frac{1}{4}(x+\sqrt{2})^{2}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\epsilon,   -\sqrt{2}<x<0\\
1-\frac{1}{4}(x-\sqrt{2})^{2}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\epsilon,   0<x<\sqrt{2}\\
1-A\epsilon e^{-\frac{x-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2\epsilon}}},   x>\sqrt{2}
\end{cases}
$$
where $A=e^{\frac{\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y+e^{-y}-1}}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{y}\right)dy+\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y+e^{-y}-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\right)dy-2}{\sqrt{2}}}\approx0.66237$.

My question is: how do I obtain this without knowledge of the exact solution? (the equation to which I want to find an asymptotic solution does not admit any form of exact solution). I can obtain the leading order solution by appropriately approximating the exponential terms in the differential equation (e.g. $e^{-\frac{y}{\epsilon}}\sim1$ where $y<O(\epsilon)$ and $e^{-\frac{y}{\epsilon}}\sim0$ where $y>O(\epsilon)$) to get:
$$
y\sim\begin{cases}
0,   x<-\sqrt{2}\\
\frac{1}{4}(x+\sqrt{2})^{2},   -\sqrt{2}<x<0\\
1-\frac{1}{4}(x-\sqrt{2})^{2},   0<x<\sqrt{2}\\
0,   x>\sqrt{2}
\end{cases}
$$
However, I'm struggling to find the first order correction. I'm trying a substitution of the form:
$$
y(x)=y_{0}(x)+k\epsilon^{\alpha}e^{\frac{S(x)}{\beta}}
$$
where $ y_{0}(x)$ is the above, piecewise quadratic, leading order solution and $S(x)$ is some $O(1)$ function to be determined, along with $k$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$, assuming $\alpha,\beta\geq0$ (but not both $0$). When I do this, I'm not able to solve for all of the unknowns and I don't see how the constant $A$ is going to be determined from the method.
Any help is greatly appreciated.